# Is the h1 tag the thing google is looking for?

Tags: search, search-engine

I've heard from a friend that I should use more h1 tags, cause that will be the first thing Google will look for. Is he right?

**EDIT**

Sorry for asking on stack overflow. I'll try web masters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a non-programming related SEO question which would be better asked on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: See https://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/#utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=ww-ww-et-b2bfooter_bsolutions, not [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that the contents of h1 tags is important for the search engines, but it works only if h1 tag really looks like the main heading on the page. It's considered goo practice to have only one h1 per page. Using many h1 tags for "increasing the importance of some search terms" usually has the opposite effect (i.e. is bad for SEO).

See also recommendations from Google in the following PDF (on p.20): https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf